# How to capture selection event in jQueryUI selectable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a few links on a webpage. They open a similar dialog window and load equal content via `$.load()`. Content has `ul` list and it use `$.selectable()` plugin:

```
$('.select-dialog-cities > ul').selectable({filter: 'li'});
```

I would like to handle the `selectableselected` event. As I have three links, I need to separate the events. Is it possible without global flags? Something like this:

```
$("#dialog_id .select-dialog-cities > ul").on("selectableselected", function(event, ui){});
```

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected, you can pass that handler in your options, with that `filter`. And as the example code below, your code should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I sad:

> load equal content via $.load(). Content has ul list

I could not assign event this way:

```
$("#dialog_id .select-dialog-cities > ul").on("selectableselected", function(event, ui){});
```

Because I forget about one moment from documentation `$.on()`:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; **they
>   must exist** at the time your code makes the call to .on().

So the solution was very easy:

```
$("#dialog_id").on("selectableselected", ".select-dialog-cities > ul", function(event, ui){});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you might also just query which elements are actually selected, like this:

```
$("#selectable").on("selectableselected", function(event, ui){
    $('.ui-selected').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

[**Example on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jaggedsoftware/XYJEN/1103/)

If you're doing this on different dialog windows, you will probably need to bind to the event every time you create a new dialog window.

Answer (score 0):

To capture that event you should provide a function to the `selected` property of the object you initialise `selectable` with. Try this:

```
$('.select-dialog-cities > ul').selectable({
    filter: 'li',
    selected: function(e, ui) {
        console.log('You chose something!');
    }
});
```

You can get information about the element that raised the event via the `selected` property of the `ui` parameter passed to the function.

More info in the [jQueryUI Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected)